# how to implement flight moving animation in google map using typescript

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, svg, angular2-template

I have a map with source and destination locations and a path is also drawn between the locations. I want to add an animated image of a flight that should move over the path. I have done the map in angular2. Please help me if anyone know the animation part in angular 2 or suggest me any link that i can refer.
Thanks in advance.

I used the below plugin for showing google map in angular 2
https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMap-directive.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voNL9.jpg)

Comment: can you paste the method you used to show the map

Comment: @antony: We are using <sebm-google-map> to create map. If you have any idea about that please suggest me or refer me any related links

Comment: Consider including the code for what you have already tried.

Comment: is it possible to give  svg image animation on google map ? i am not sure about it...

Comment: @ishmael: I have done by referring this link https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMap-directive.html

Comment: Hi did u got ur answer..???? am also facing same issue

Comment: @AbijithAjayan Vahid --- Did you get solution for moving animation in google map ?